# Memory Pointers and Arrays

Tags: c

I have this struct:

```
struct table{
    int miny,maxy,maxa;
    int** list;
};
```

and its subsequent typedef:

```
typedef struct table *StatTable;
```

So, my doubt is the following:
On the initialisation of a `struct table` I do this and it might work fine:

```
StatTable newStatistic(int min,int max,int maxauts){
    StatTable aux=malloc(sizeof(StatTable));
    aux->miny=min;
    aux->maxy=max;
    aux->maxa=maxauts;
    aux->list=calloc(((max-min))*(maxauts+1),sizeof(int));
    return aux;
}
```

Since I declared that list as an int ** can I implement a function this way?

```
int get(StatTable st,int ano,int nAut){
    return st->list[ano-getMinYear(st)][nAut];
}
```

Comment: Why not compile and see for yourself?

Comment: The problem is that it's a module from a project and I'm seg faulting... Just to know if is this the cause...

Comment: if you have seg fault and you've narrowed it down to the get() function, my guess is that your'e accessing out of the `list` range. i.e there is no item at `list[x][y]`, you should validate the index before using `[]`.

Comment: it will compile. But runtime error(seg fault) depends on what pointer it holds.

Comment: So, for example to prevent the seg fault, I can put an if clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
StatTable aux=malloc(sizeof(StatTable));
```

...is wrong. You're allocating the size of a pointer to `aux`. You should allocate the size of the structure instead:

```
StatTable aux=malloc(sizeof(struct table));
```

Instead allocating one contiguous block of memory like this:

```
 aux->list=calloc(((max-min))*(maxauts+1),sizeof(int));
```

...you should allocate your 2D pointers like this:

```
aux->list = calloc(max - min, sizeof(*aux->list));
for (int i=0; i<max-min; i++)
    aux->list[i] = calloc(maxauts + 1, sizeof(**aux->list));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
StatTable aux=malloc(sizeof(StatTable));
```

This statement will not create an variable of `struct table`. `StatTable` is a `typedef` for a pointer to the struct variable so `sizeof(StatTable)` gives size of a pointer so this statement wont allocate space for a variable of structure.
Therefore

```
aux->miny=min;
aux->maxy=max;
aux->maxa=maxauts
```

these statements results in `segmentation fault` since memory is not allocated for them.

To create a variable and then to make `aux` a pointer to it use,

```
 StatTable aux=malloc(sizeof(struct table));
```